# Capturing additional mouse buttons

Tags: c++, windows, mouse

Is there a way to capture presses of additional mouse buttons if mouse has more that 2 of them? According to MSDN WM_XBUTTONDOWN is sent for 2 additional buttons only. I need a solution which will work for any mouse, so using features of special mouse drivers is prohibited. I've found in DirectInput documentation enum Mouse_Device which contains constants describing up to 8 buttons. Can be DirectInput used for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about raw input via the `WM_INPUT` message?

There's a decent explanation of how it works [here](http://toymaker.info/Games/html/raw_input.html).

Comment: `RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_DOWN` and `RI_MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON_1` (and similar) map to the same constant, so there's support for effectively only 5 buttons with this API.